# Populate Plist to UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist, unrecognized-selector

I have a problem with my code and i can't figure out what's wrong.

My code is this :

```
@implementation FirstViewController {
NSDictionary *countriesDetails;
NSArray *countriesList;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"countries" withExtension:@"plist"];
    countriesDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    countriesList = countriesDetails.allKeys;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return countriesDetails.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[countriesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"country"];

    return cell;
}
```

My plist file is this :

```
<dict>
<key>Paris</key>
<dict>
    <key>country</key>
    <string>France</string>
    <key>chName</key>
    <string>Paris</string>
    <key>chlink</key>
    <string>www.paris.com</string>
</dict>
<key>Rome</key>
<dict>
    <key>country</key>
    <string>Italy</string>
    <key>chName</key>
    <string>Rome</string>
    <key>chlink</key>
    <string>www.rome.com</string>
</dict>
```

So my app will have multiple tableviews, and the first one shows all the countries I have on my plist.

My XCode shows no error, but when I am running the app it crashes and this appears:

> 2015-05-26 23:34:53.362 newApp[1511:95592] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde31f242d0
>   2015-05-26 23:34:53.366 neaApp[1511:95592] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde31f242d0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `countriesList` consists of `NSString`s, not `NSDictionary`s.
Change your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[countriesDetails objectForKey:[countriesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectForKey:@"country"];

    return cell;
}
```